# Matlab doesn't detect Visual Studio C++ compiler

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, visual-studio-2012, mex

When trying to setup Matlab with OpenCV addon I can't setup Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler.

I tried to reinstall Visual Studio, however it doesn't help. I managed to setup MinGW-w64 Compiler, but I need to use Visual Studio C++ compiler.

I suspect that something is wrong with registers, but I can't pinpoint what.

Thank you for your help !

---

---

---

Matlab: 2016a
Visual Studio: 2012 Professional
OS: Windows 10

Output when running command "mex -setup c++ -v" in Matlab:

```
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0' InstallationFolder ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 11.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\').
... Looking for environment variable 'VS110COMNTOOLS' ...Yes ('F:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\').
... Looking for file 'F:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the next steps to complete my configuration:

- install MATLAB
- install Visual Studio (2013 or 2015) (you can download the community
  edition for free)
- install OpenCV (the official 3.1.0 installer), and set PATH
  environment variable as explained
- download mexopencv
        in MATLAB, first call addpath as required, then run mexopencv.make with the appropriate options